# python dataframe merge columns according to other column values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What I want to do is merge columns according to values in another column
It is better illustrated with a simple example:
I have a dataframe with 5 columns:

```
| player_num    | team_1.x  | team_1.y  | team_2.x  | team_2.y  |
|------------   |---------- |---------- |---------- |---------- |
| 1             | x_1       | y_1       | x_2       | y_2       |
| 4             | x_3       | y_3       | x_4       | y_4       |
| 8             | x_5       | y_5       | x_6       | y_6       |
```

I want to get the following table:

```
| x     | y     |
|-----  |-----  |
| x_1   | y_1   |
| x_3   | y_3   |
| x_6   | y_6   |
```

where the columns are filled with values from team_1.x and team_1.y for rows of players with number less than 5 and values from team_2.x and team_2.y for rows of players with number bigger than 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Numpy's np.where for this:

```py
import numpy as np
...
df['x'] = np.where(df['player_num'] < 5, df['team_1.x'], df['team_2.x'])
df['y'] = np.where(df['player_num'] < 5, df['team_1.y'], df['team_2.y'])
```

EDIT:

```py
# Extract column names and remove prefix to get a list of x,y,z, etc.
cols = [col.split('.')[1] for col in list(df) if 'team_' in col]

# Loop over and create new column for each prefix (x, y, z, etc)
for col in cols:
    col1 = 'team_1.' + col
    col2 = 'team_2.' + col
    df[col] = np.where(df['player_num']<5, df[col1], df[col2])
```

Comment: Can you make this solution work automatically for the columns with the prefixes 'team_1' and 'team_2'?

Comment: If i understand correctly.. you have multiple columns like team_1.x, team_1.y, team_1.z, etc and same for team_2 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can segregate the dataframe based on the conditions followed by concatenating the results

```
l = df.loc[df["player_num"].lt(5), ["team_1.x", "team_1.y"]].rename(columns={"team_1.x": "x", "team_1.y": "y"})
g = df.loc[df["player_num"].gt(5), ["team_2.x", "team_2.y"]].rename(columns={"team_2.x": "x", "team_2.y": "y"})
df_res = pd.concat([l, g])
print(df_res)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not at all an elegant solution, but it should work...

```
for i in df.loc[:, 'player_num']:
    index = df.loc[df.loc[:, 'player_num'] == i].index[0]

    if i >= 5:
        df.loc[index, 'x'] = df.loc[index, 'team_2.x']
        df.loc[index, 'y'] = df.loc[index, 'team_2.y']

    else:
        df.loc[index, 'x'] = df.loc[index, 'team_1.x']
        df.loc[index, 'y'] = df.loc[index, 'team_1.x']
```

Comment: I actually have quite a few columns with the prefixes "team_1" and "team_2" so I'm looking for a more general solution. If I won't find it I will definitely use this. Thanks !